# Android emulator error message, running React Native demo from react-native-cli

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio-2.2, react-native-cli

ERROR:

```
SyntaxError: Strict mode does not allow function declarations in a lexically nested statement. (http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:24821)
```

system:

- win 10 x64
- android studio 2.2.3
- AVC  Nexus_5x_API_23

I used **react-native-cli** and `react-native run-android` the CMD states `BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1 mins 10.929 secs
Starting the app on emulator-5554 (adb -s emulator-5554 shell am start -n com.albums/.MainActivity)..`

but I get the error above

[Error of emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHxpd.jpg)

Comment: Did you try to find if you are using a "use strict" statement in some place? If you find something, share the code

Comment: I searched the entire build and still no.  See search results in ST3
[link](http://recordit.co/4tzO8IOc3I)